# Having multiple parent activities for one activity?

Tags: java, android

So I have two separate activities in my app that both have a 'Contact' button on them. Clicking on either button on both activity launches the same 'ContactActivity'. Now problem is when I want to implement up navigation for this activity, how would I do it for both depending on activity I'm on?

Reason being is because when on ContactActivity, and hitting up navigation I'm brought back to the parent activity defined, in this case two activities are technically the parent depending on which you call the Contact intent from. I know that I could just duplicate the ContactActivity into another, and use separate ones, but I just feel that there could be a simpler way of doing this.

Comment: Why don't you call startActivityForResult()? It returns to the "parent" activity by default.

Comment: What do you mean? If I called startActivityForResult for each to ContactActivity, it will put in an up nav for me? And I won't have to provide the parent via XML?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not ideal, perhaps you can pass a parameter in the intent you use to run the child activity that you can evaluate on onBackPressed().

My reasoning is: A and B are C's parent activities. If you are in A and call C, you can do:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, C.class);
intent.putExtra("parent", "A")
```

In C you get that parameter:

```
mParentActivity = intent.getStringExtra("parent");
```

Then in onBackPressed():

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mParentActivity.equals("A")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (mParentActivity.equals("B")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you are in the quest for reputation points, then answering 3 y/o questions with almost no visibility is pretty futile I am afraid :) I recommend my [StackUnderflow](https://github.com/MarcinOrlowski/StackUnderflow) script a Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey script that'd warn you next time about that.

Comment: I totally failed to notice the date on the original post, but thanks! Rep points is not something I'm concerned with but answering ancient questions isn't either XD